# Ошибка при выполнении кода на stackoverflow, но не на других сайтах

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, сниппеты

Создал код с использованием библиотеки jQuery. При запуске его на [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4hkc1dz/) код работает, но при вставке с помощью тега "Фрагмент когда на JS/HTML/CSS" выдает ошибку в консоли:
"message": "Script error."

Код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#more").on("click", function() {
    $("ul").toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
button {
  border: 0;
}

ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="more" value="More..." />
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

**UPD:** Протестировал в браузерах (OS: *Win 7x64*):

*Google Chrome:  69.0.3497.100 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит) - error*

*Opera: 56.0.3051.43 - error*

*Firefox: 62.0.3 (64-бит) - work*

*IE 11: 11.0.9600.19137 - error*

**UPD 2:** Похоже, баг с самим jQuery и потенциальной уязвимостью XSS кода песочницы. Если заменить версию библиотеки jQuery с 1.11.3 на 3.3.1 - пример заработает:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#more").on("click", function() {
    $("ul").toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
button {
  border: 0;
}

ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="more" value="More..." />
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Здесь вроде бы [работает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhIZD.png).

Comment: @älёxölüt у меня (Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100) таки выдаёт ошибку, и совершенно непонятно чем она вызвана

Comment: В фаерфоксе работает, в хроме не работает

Comment: В консольке написано `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: Возможно, действительно, зависит от браузера. Сейчас посмотрю...

Comment: Да, это проблема с одной стороны в настройках iframe, для сниппетов, в котором по максимуму все ограничено, с другой стороны в jquery, который в некоторых случаях создает `iframe` для получения дефолтных значений, и из-за этого происходит ошибка.

Comment: [раз](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245134/282647) и [два](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317335/2881286)

Comment: В общем, проблема похоже на интеграцию jQuery с sandbox сайта. Как понял, баг самого jQuery. Если же обновить версию с указанной в коде 1.11.3 на 3.3.1 - пример заработает.

Comment: Почему вопрос на мете? Он же должен быть на SO. Может перенесет кто-нибудь?

Comment: @AntonSorokin, Мета Stack Overflow на русском – это сайт, где участники обсуждают технические и организационные аспекты работы сайта Stack Overflow на русском. Мета отделена от главного сайта, чтобы сократить информационный шум на основном ресурсе, и одновременно обеспечить подходящее место для вопросов о том как и почему Stack Overflow на русском работает так, а не иначе. Мета предназначена для: [...] - для сообщений о дефектах или предложений по улучшению сайта и правил сообщества;[...] https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @Kosmos но разве проблема не в jQuery?

Comment: @AntonSorokin, с чего его переносить, если в нём о проблеме SO&