# Ошибки при запуске любого фрагмента кода

Tags: дефект, сниппеты, редактор

При запуске любого фрагмента кода на HTML/CSS/Javascript у меня выскакивают три надоедливые ошибки, которые мешают смотреть результат.

[image: error1]
[image: error2]
[image: error3]

Видимо, эти ошибки только у меня. Что мне делать? Они мне уже сильно надоели.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при выполнении кода на stackoverflow, но не на других сайтах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8127/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stackoverflow-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85)

Comment: @Grundy Блин, ну там даже ответа нет.